# Passing aweber API info via a function in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, aweber

So, I am trying to connect to the Aweber API in codeigniter.  I have a function that retrieves all relevant data for an account, but I still have to put these three lines at the beginning of every function using the API

```
list ($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessKey, $accessSecret, $account_id) = $this->get_aweber_info();

$aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$account = $aweber->getAccount($accessKey, $accessSecret);
```

Is it possible to make that shorter?  I'd love to just say

```
get_aweber_connection();
```

I've tried a couple of different things but none are working?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a helper and call it from wherever your want but I would suggest to create a library that will handle all the Aweber api calls and will initialize everything on its constructor.

This way you will have to just load the library and then interact with Aweber and you will have all your Aweber calls at one class.